# Disable a check box after the the checkvalue enter into the database

Tags: javascript

book.php

```
<td><input type="hidden" name="bus_fare" id="bus_fare" value="<?php echo $row['price'];?>"> 1<br>
 <input type="checkbox" name="seat[]" id="seat_1"  value="1" onclick="seat_display(this.value);" /></td>
<td>
<input type="hidden" name="bus_fare" id="bus_fare" value=""> 3<br> 
<input type="checkbox" name="seat[]" id="seat_3"  value="3" onclick="seat_display(this.value);" /></td>
<td>
 <input type="hidden" name="bus_fare" id="bus_fare" value=""> 5 <br>
<input type="checkbox" name="seat[]" id="seat_5"  value="5" onclick="seat_display(this.value);" /></td>

<input type="text" id="total_seats" name="total_seats" value="" readonly />
```

javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var tot = 0;
function seat_display(val)
{       
seat_no = "seat_"+val;
var s_no = document.getElementById(seat_no).value; 

var fare = parseInt(document.getElementById('bus_fare').value);

if(document.getElementById(seat_no).checked) {

document.getElementById('total_seats').value += s_no+",";

tot=tot+fare;   
}
else
{
    tot=tot-fare;
    var arr = document.getElementById('total_seats').value;

    var seatno = arr.split(",");

    for( var i=0; i<seatno.length; i++ )
    {
        if(seatno[i] == s_no )          
            seatno.splice(i,1);     
    }       
    document.getElementById('total_seats').value = seatno;      
    if(tot < 0){
     tot=0; }        
}   
document.getElementById('total_amt').value = tot;
}

</script>
```

I want to disable those check boxes which are already checked and the values (checkbox) has already been sent to the database. Each checkbox has it's own unique value, so once an user check 1 or multiple checkbox in the book.php and the checkbox values are sent to the database, when next time another user comes he/she should see the already checked checkboxes are disabled, he/she cant select them. I want to use javascript for this. Any help?

Comment: I dont understand why you are using the name bus_fare repeatedly. It will be having only the last value. All the previous values will be overridden. I think you can get values from database before building the form . If there is value already present disable it.

Comment: i ve to call the ids with the same name thats why i m using the same name bus_fare.. how can i disable a checkbox after its value got inserted into database ??

Comment: can you please give what value are you adding to database or atleast the column names

Comment: the checkboxes which are checked are being displayed here " <input type="text" id="total_seats" name="total_seats" value="" readonly />  " , these values got inserted to the database according to the checkbox value

Answer (score 0):

Try this method

HTML

```
<input id="inlineCheckbox1" type="checkbox" value="1" name="spam[]">
<input id="inlineCheckbox1" type="checkbox" value="2" name="spam[]">
<input id="inlineCheckbox1" type="checkbox" value="3" name="spam[]">
```

Script

```
//Data from server already booked seats no
var data={
    "bookedseats": [
        "1",
        "2"
    ]
};
var ass=data.bookedseats
$("input[name='spam[]']").each( function(i,j) {
    if(jQuery.inArray($(j).val(), ass) != -1){
    $(j).prop('disabled', true);//this disables already booked seats no from server data              
    }

});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/gANsn/)

Comment: you update the database once user booked seats.then accessing that specific bus table to get the booked seats to update when the new user is logged

Comment: i want to disable the te textbox once the value got inserted to the DB

Comment: ok thats not a problem in using checkbox onchange function you update the db and get updated response and do the function

Comment: i just want to first fetch the seat numbers (checkbox value) inserted into the database according to the bus_name in javascript, i can update my databse aftre that can you write me that code please ??

Comment: fetch details using php ajax